# Trying to create an overlapping element to the screen when a card is clicked

Tags: css, flexbox

Basically I want a new element to override every other element to give the illusion that a new screen has appeared when a card is clicked. Looks like I did it but the problem appears when I resize the screen, then that elements looks very off.

This is the css code that I used:

```
.overlap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #4f00e7;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And also the site Im working on: https://strong-salamander-b1af56.netlify.app/portfolio

Thank you and have a nice day!

[image]

Comment: You have a number of conditions that are not in code IN the question; please add a minimal reproducible example right here in the question (perhaps a snippet) You tag this as `flexbox`  but there is no flexbox in this questions coce.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with `position: fixed`

```css
.overlap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #4f00e7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
content

<div class="overlap">overlap</div>
```